# Tube Fipy 3D sweep meshing

Tags: python-3.x, mesh, fipy

I would like to **sweep_like 3D meshing** a **hollow cylinder**, is there any mesh modules in Fipy for this?? 
how to aim this goal by Fipy or other libraries in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "sweep_like"? If any mesh is fine, [meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo#tube) is probably the most straightforward solution.

Comment: sweep like in 'Abaqus' is similar to O-grid mesh type in Ansys. From the inner wall of cylinder or tube to outer side, mesh volumes expand (along radius); mesh density becomes less along radius toward outer body.  for an element volume,  there are 4 element along radius, 4 are circular by center of cylinder in the body, and 4 along cylinder body length.

Comment: I get it now, you're actually looking to mesh a 3D _solid_. There are plenty of mesh generators out there. Gmsh is one, pygalmesh another, mshr, meshpy, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy can read [Gmsh](http://gmsh.info/) meshes. If you only want the mesh in python and won't be using FiPy to solve PDEs, then I would follow the suggestion of @Nico Schlömer.

Comment: Before anything else, Thank you for your reply:
How could change code 'mesh = CylindricalGrid2D(dr, dz, Lr, Lz)' for 'dr' gradual increase from the inside toward outside of the cylinder wall.
What does ' + [[r0], [0]]' do if being added to the end of aforementioned code.
How to mesh from an specified radius far from origin of the cylinder for inner boundary to outer boundary.

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.

Comment: I post the question entitled "FiPy cylidrical O'Grid 3D growing sweep meshing [CylindricalGrid2D]" in new address:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150013/fipy-cylidrical-ogrid-3d-growing-sweep-meshing-cylindricalgrid2d