# FiPy Hollow cylidrical O'Grid 3D growing sweep meshing [CylindricalGrid2D]

Tags: python, fipy, mesh-network

I would be grateful if anyone could help me to solve the following questions,

1. How could change code '**mesh = CylindricalGrid2D(dr, dz, Lr, Lz)**' for '**dr**' gradual increase from the inside toward outside of the Hollow cylinder wall.
2. What does ' **+ [[r0], [0]]**' do if being added to the end of aforementioned code.
3. How to mesh from an specified radius far from origin of the cylinder (for inner boundary of cylinder) to outer boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can pass a list of sizes to `dr` and `dz` (it looks like you have to do them both). E.g.,

   ```py
   mesh = fp.CylindricalGrid2D(dr=[1, 2, 3, 4], dz=[dz] * 50)
   ```
2. `+ [[r0], [0]]` offsets the inner radius to `r0`
3. See 2